# How to print matrix in winform label

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I need to print a matrix into a winform label. Is there any possible to format the text in a label?
My matrix looks like this:

[matrix http://imgupload.sk/images/h/2/h275io2p0c91mahp9ndv.png](http://imgupload.sk/images/h/2/h275io2p0c91mahp9ndv.png)

Comment: I would use GDI+ for this instead.

Comment: This console is running out from Winform aplication. How can I use GDI+ ??

Comment: @Andre http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/gdi_plus12092005070041AM/gdi_plus.aspx

Comment: It is not impossible.  Use String.Format() and select a fixed-pitch font for the label.

Answer (score 0):

I saved matrix into txt file and then show this file in richTextbox